# SWRevealViewController reload another uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using `SWRevealViewController` as a settings menu for my app

Is there a way for me to control a `UIView` in another `viewcontroller`?

I'm changing the view by the data in my database, I can successfully save and update the data, also can change if I change the front view by tab bar

but using `SWRevealViewController` will not change instantly

Any suggestions?

[when I click on different chart icon I want to change my view on the left right away](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBCUL.png)

Comment: Show some image on what you want to achieve

Comment: I uploaded a image,Thankyou!

Comment: have you tried to use delegate after creating that vc to tell it to update the value?

Comment: no I haven't, I'm new to swift so not really familiar with delegate, thank you very much, I'll try work on that!

Comment: Hello, I tried using code like 
'let secondViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController

self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)'
but still no luck